Is there a connection between quantum state probability and Bayes' theorem?
In statistical physics, the probability that an electron is in the i-th quantum state is given by the following equation (eq. 1):
$$
p_i = \frac{e^{-\beta E_i}}{\sum_j e^{-\beta E_j}}
$$
This formula resembles Bayes' theorem (eq. 2):
$$
P(A_i|B) = \frac{P(B|A_i) P(A_i)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B|A_i) P(A_i)}{\sum_j P(B|A_j) P(A_j)} 
$$
My question is:
Do these two equations have a relationship, or is it just a coincidence? If a relationship does exist, what do events A and B represent in eq. 1?

I don't see how this resembles a non-trivial Bayes' formula.

Can you clarify in what way do you think the first formula "resembles" the second? Is it just because they both have a sum in the denominator? For starters, each summand in the first formula has one term but each summand in the second is the product of two terms. Moreover the first formula has nothing to do with conditional probabilities.

Correction: "Is it just because they both have a sum in the denominator?" to "Is it just because they both have a sum in the denominator and one particular term of that sum in the numerator?"

It's just a coincidence. The first isn't dealing with conditional probabilities. I suppose really the only thing is that the sums in the denominators serve to normalize the relative probabilities in the numerators so that all probabilities sum to $1$, but that's true of any set of numbers used to describe probabilities.

Thanks for your reply. This make sense. All the normalized probabilities have this structure, but they are not conditional probabilities.
